# xmllint: Relax-NG validity error : Element tests has extra content

Tags: xml, validation, relaxng, xmllint

I'm trying to make xmllint to validate this schema. Unfortunately I came to some strange issue. It looks like xmllint interpretes wrong **optional** arguments without **interleave** tag included. Here is some test schema with misspelled tag *person* which should be signalized by xmllint. Unfortunately xmllint is raporting some other non-existing bug. Please take a look maybe I'm doing something wrong:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<grammar xmlns="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0">

<define name="testproject">
    <element name="testproject">
        <ref name="overview"/>
        <ref name="tests"/>
    </element>
</define>

<define name="overview">
    <element name="overview">
        <ref name="title"/>
        <oneOrMore>
            <ref name="person"/>
        </oneOrMore>
    </element>
</define>

<define name="tests">
    <element name="tests">

        <choice>
            <attribute name="file"/>

            <group>
                <ref name="title"/>
                <optional>
                    <ref name="field"/>
                </optional>
                <optional>
                    <ref name="field2"/>
                </optional>
                <optional>
                    <ref name="field3"/>
                </optional>

                <choice>
                    <zeroOrMore>
                        <ref name="test"/>
                    </zeroOrMore>
                    <zeroOrMore>
                        <ref name="tests"/>
                    </zeroOrMore>
                </choice>
            </group>
        </choice>
    </element>
</define>

<define name="test">
    <element name="test">
        <attribute name="name"/>

        <interleave>
            <optional>
                <ref name="title"/>
            </optional>
            <ref name="field"/>
            <zeroOrMore>
                <ref name="person"/>
            </zeroOrMore>
        </interleave>
    </element>
</define>

<define name="title">
    <element name="title">
        <text/>
    </element>
</define>

<define name="field">
    <element name="field">
        <text/>
    </element>
</define>

<define name="field2">
    <element name="field2">
        <text/>
    </element>
</define>

<define name="field3">
    <element name="field3">
        <text/>
    </element>
</define>

<define name="person">
    <element name="person">
        <text/>
    </element>
</define>

<start>
    <ref name="testproject"/>
</start>
</grammar>
```

And xml file content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<testproject>
<overview>
    <title>
        some title
    </title>
    <person>J33nn</person>
</overview>

<tests>
    <title>
        Some title test
    </title>
    <field>as</field> 
    <test name="TestName">
        <title>Some title</title>

        <field>
            dasdasd
        </field>

        <peron>J33nn</peron>
    </test>
</tests>
</testproject>
```

And instead of reporting misspelled tag *peron* it reports something like this:

**element field: Relax-NG validity error : Element tests has extra content: field**

Answer (score 3):

When I run `xmllint` on your XML file with your schema, I get the same error you report. However, note that the error is reported for `<field>as</field>`, which makes no sense whatsoever because this element should be acceptable in that position.

If I use `jing` to perform the validation, I get:

```
test.xml:23:16: error: element "peron" not allowed anywhere; expected the element end-tag or element "person"
```

which is a more sensible result. I'm certain that `jing` is right and `xmllint` is wrong.

Comment: True **jing** works well but wanted to force **xmllint** to work :/

Comment: To get xmllint to work, you'd have to get the source and debug it, or pay someone to debug it, or get the developers of xmllint to care about the problem you've found and debug it.

Comment: From what has been reported, it looks to at least one outside observer as if xmllint is working fine.  Is the schema valid? no.  Does xmllint say it's invalid? yes.  Your problem is that xmllint's diagnosis is poor and its error message not helpful, not that it is producing a wrong result.  No system always produces good error messages.

Comment: @C.M.Sperberg-McQueen xmllint is wrong, end of story.